# How can we authenticate with JAAS using a file with Bcrypt passwords as authentication source?

Tags: authentication, bcrypt, jaas, properties-file

For a demo version of our product, we currently use a 3rd party `FileLogin` module named `com.tagish.auth.FileLogin`  to insert into JAAS. This `LoginModule` was originally added in 2005 and still uses MD5 to protect passwords. The format of the file that is read from is:

```
Username:Password_MD5[:Role][:Role]...
```

Since this LoginModule is not used in live environments (we force our users into using LDAP in live environments, which disables the `FileLogin LoginModule`), we haven't yet seen the need to change this. However, using unsalted MD5 for passwords is not optimal and might put us in a less than optimal light, especially since the properties file is freely accessible. We are researching how we can maintain the use of a .properties file (because those are easy to add new users for trial purposes) but also use Bcrypt for password hashing.

Our hopes for this are:

1. Preferably, we hope to find an existing solution implementing file-based authentication using Bcrypt that we can replace our FileLogin class with that requires minimal changes.
2. If that is not possible, we already found the source code for the FileLogin module we currently use, publically available on Github (https://github.com/tauceti2/jaas-rdbms). The idea with this is that we update this source code to support Bcrypt using the JBCrypt library or comparable. This does not seem a very complicated task, but it would require additional maintenance.
3. We would rather not create our own LoginModel implementation because that is a very complicated and involved process where we can't be sure that our solution remains bugfree.

We have tried to Google for a solution, but couldn't find any existing solutions that fit our needs. There are solutions, but they are usually part of a larger project like JBoss, Karaf,... so they're not easily ported to our needs.

It appears that our best bet is adapting our existing solution to support bcrypt using the source code we found, First though, we wanted to check if the SO community has a better idea.

Is adapting the jaas-RDBMS source code the best option here?